When can I use bootstrapping in a microsimulation model?
I'm investigating uncertainty in a linked series of microsimulation models, the outputs of each feeding into the next.
The first model (model A) generates individuals by resampling them - using a stratified sampling approach - from historical data, and shifting them forwards in time.  These individuals then enter the rest of the modelling pipeline, where other stochastic processes add further noise to the outputs.  It's likely that a lot of the uncertainty in the pipeline arises from who is selected in this step of the process.
The most obvious approach to the problem would be to just run the model pipeline a number of times with different seeds - but this is likely to take a very long time.  I wondered about the option of bootstrapping the sample from model A to create several different samples, which I could then feed through the rest of the pipeline.
Would this essentially have the same effect?  Or am I missing something?
